# Wireless Connection Needs authentication

Tags: wireless

I Have a TP LINK TL-WN722N wireless usb adapter. I have to use it because all onboard wifi chips never work. Here is the wireless info script: https://pastebin.com/q7eFC5Fm

What happens is my adapter status becomes disconnected and asks repeatedly for my wifi password. I cannot stop this process until I unplug the adapter and plug it back in.

Paste for dmesg command:
    https://pastebin.com/VykRHHhf

Comment: Use only WPA2-AES.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Intel wireless device *and* a TP-Link TL-WN722N and the Intel works much better. I am going to recommend some changes to you and I suspect that, if you undertake all of them, the internal Intel device will work very well.

First, turn off power saving in Network Manager. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Next, I recommend another change to Network Manager.

```
 sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Edit the file so that it now reads:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

After making any needed changes, save the file (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit nano (Ctrl+x).

Reboot the computer.

Next, as has been noted, many Linux drivers, including ath9k_htc and including iwlwifi hate hate hate TKIP.

Please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

After all these changes, is there any improvement?

Comment: I don't have a NetworkManager.conf file or directory. In it there is only dispatcher.d, dnsmasq.d, system-connections, VPN (folders), NetworkManger.conf (file)

In NetworkManager.conf:
    
    [main]
    plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
    dns=dnsmasq
    
    [ifupdown]
    managed=false

Comment: I don’t understand. You say you don’t have the file and then tell me you *do* have the file and what’s in it. Please add the [device] stanza as I suggested.

Comment: My mistake I meant to say I do not have the conf.d directory. When I run your command I get this: "sed: can't read /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*: No such file or directory"

Comment: I see now that you are running 14.04. Please skip the power saving step and move forward with all the other steps.

Comment: Is there anything else that can be done? it asked for authentication again. Is it because the wireless usb is faulty?

Comment: Did you make the changes to the router and reboot it?

Comment: Yes, the changes were made.

Comment: Please pastebin: `dmesg | grep -e ath -e wlan` and also: sudo iwlist scan` And give me the link.

Comment: For the second comment I get: lo interface doesn't support scanning.

Comment: Please humor an old driver dog. Unplug the USB, reboot and open a terminal and do: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` Does the internal device connect and stay connected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69984/discussion-between-jinzu-and-chili555).

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem of continuous re-entering the correct WiFi password with an old ASUS Eee PC 900HA (AR2427 802.11bg Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)) running Linux Lite 3.8.

The problem was that my wireless access point accepted only 802.11n, while the adapter only supports 802.11bg.

I solved this  by logging in with another computer to the access point (in my case 192.168.0.1) with a browser, and changing the wireless network settings from 802.11n-only to mixed (802.11b/g/n). Note that this can also be done with a wired (ethernet cable) connection on the same computer.